# JUNOS firewall issues

Tags: firewall, nat, junos

I am in the process of trying to setup a Juniper SRX240. I have been using the screenOS firewalls for sometime and having some difficulty adjusting.I haven't quickly been able to find a way to do in screenOS terms a MIP. Basically I have over 20 Public IP addresses I need to be able to map to internal IP addresses and create rules based on those mappings. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIPs are basically just static 1:1 NAT - that might help searching the docs (sorry, still all ScreenOS here).

This looks like it might be useful: http://www.mail-archive.com/juniper-nsp@puck.nether.net/msg06827.html

Answer (score 0):

Think it should be in the untrusted interface page on top should be MIP link

Comment: This is in screenOS not JUNOS E

Comment: Im indeed talking abour screenOS..

Answer (score 0):

James' post should be enough to get the IP's up, but in short, JunOS does lack the sort of nice template mechanism you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool to translate ScrenOS configurations to Junos. i haven't tested it yet, but im sure it will help you,

[ScreenOS to Junos Trasnlator](https://i2j.juniper.net/s2j/index.jsp)

You will need an Juniper Account.